# Extract date out of datetime in c# and sort using datatables plugin - ASP.NET Core MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display only date from timestamp. Below is the code in my "view" it works fine but I couldn't sort it.

```
<td class="align-middle">@item.Arrival_ts.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")</td>
```

I am using a plugin called "DataTables" which automatically sorts columns in table without any issue as long the data types are right. In above situation since I am converting my date to string format, my plugin is not sorting in right order. I found this out by using ticks. For example if I display datetime as numbers and then use sorting then it works fine. Like below,

```
   <td class="align-middle">@item.Arrival_ts.Value.Ticks</td>
```

But again I want to display it as date like dd-MMM-yyyy and not as numbers. Ideal solution would be to extract date from timestamp and display it as date and keeping its data type as date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DataTable's [Orthogonal Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) options, specifically the [options for additing HTML attributes](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5)

In your case, you can add a `data-sort` attribute to your `td` elements:

```
<td class="align-middle" data-sort="@item.Arrival_ts.Value.Ticks">
    @item.Arrival_ts.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
</td>
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Frank it worked. I was trying to sort this for hourssss. Thank you So much. Much appreciate it